# Asynchronous processing of HTTP requests in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, coffeescript

I have a node.js project, which has a [async::queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue), which is filled by `App::add()`.

This is the code I use to create the server:

```
app = new App config
server = http.createServer (req, res) ->
  app.add req, res, (err) ->
    res.headers = 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    res.end JSON.stringify error: err
.listen config.port
```

`App::add()` takes the paramters from `req` and adds a task to the queue with the callback.
The queue is processed with a function which ends `end`. If an error occures, it will be given out to the user.

Works fine, so far. But when do multiple requests in parallel, only one request at the time is processed.

**I tried:**

- A `console.log` at the end of the `http.createServer`-callback and it was called immediately, but the next request is only processed after the first ended.
- A `console.log` at the beginning of `App::add()`, same as above

How do I handle concurrent requests?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

To clear some things up, this is what I want:

1. Many many clients request the service to download a zip
2. They line up in a queue, `n` are processed at a time
3. Everyone get's their zip, as soon as it's finished

**Edit 2:**

I tried to use the [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), but this doesn't help much, because I have to end the `res` anyways.

**Edit 3:**

I tried to return a stream without closing, but no success either. 
I'm a bit desperate, maybe I'll just forward people to another server where they can download their file.

Comment: You could use websockets. Load a page after the initial request, then on each callback from the queue emit the data to the page. Just make sure you're not blocking the event loop with the queue and make use of `process.nextTick()`.

Comment: How are you returning the data? As in what format.

Comment: Either a zip file or an error as Application/JSON.

Comment: supply a code for your App.add function

Comment: App.add() parses the parameters and adds an item to the queue in less than a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS, like javascript in your browser, is single threaded. That means it can process only one continuous block of code at a time. In your example (since you haven't supplied a code for your queue processing, I assume that passed function is the actual processing code). Since it don't have any I/O (that means it don't block on waiting for something from external source like file system or database), the function's logic must fully complete before nodejs can start processing another event.

If you need more details, here's the first link I've googled about how nodejs works in concurrent environment: http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. I know, that node is single-threaded. The http server takes a new request after the last ended (with `res.end()`. But I can't imagine that there's no way to process requests asynchronously. 

Websockets as mentioned by @Ben are an idea, but not ideal.

Comment: you need to give more context into your App code and client code, there are no problems in your basic snippet.